# getting result of a method of smart contract that don't change any state variables

Tags: contract-invocation, php, explorer-api

I know in ethereum if a method of smart contract don't change state variables we can see it's result without making any transaction.

now I want to know how can see result of this method programatically?

for example by api of an explorer website that I can send some data to it and it show me some results.

I'm using php. so please don't offer me web3.js or python and so on.

for example I want to get result of `totalSupply` method of a smart contract called `DS2Token` on `ropsten` network in this address: `0x53778036dce23a22303142923316af257d7ee813`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine someone, somewhere, has written a web3 implementation for PHP, but regardless of that, you can do this via simple HTTP calls to a node, or a proxy such as infura.

To read from a function, you need to know its signature and the parameters you want to pass. For `totalSupply()`, this is simply the first 4 bytes of the keccak256 hash of the function name as a string, i.e. `keccak256("totalSupply()")`, which is `0x18160ddd`. You can set this as the `data` for the transaction, and your contract's address as the `to` field, and then make a POST request to `eth_call`. In curl, this would look something like:

```
curl https://ropsten.infura.io/ \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params": [
    {"from": "0x53778036dce23a22303142923316af257d7ee813",
     "to": "0x53778036dce23a22303142923316af257d7ee813",
     "gas": "0x76c0","gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000","value": "0x0",
     "data": "0x18160ddd"}, "latest"],"id":1}'
```

The `from` and `gasPrice` values can be anything, but `gas` needs to be large enough to allow completion of your read operation.

You will get a result along the lines of `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000052b7d2c7f6fac568ea0000"}`.

Then, simply convert the received hex number into decimal, and you will have your total supply.

Comment: I found `gas`,`gasPrice`,`value` are optional in `eth_call` method and I can only use `from`,`to` and `data`. thanks for your help :)